# data.table evaluation 1/0 not equal to TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the code snippet:

```
library(data.table)
foo <- data.table(a = rep(c(1, 0), 5), b = c(rep('bar', 5), rep('baz', 5)))
```

then this is correct:

```
> foo[, sum(b == 'bar')]
[1] 5
```

But this is not:

```
> foo[, sum(b[a] == 'bar')]
[1] 5
```

Which could be corrected by:

```
> foo[, sum(b[a == 1] == 'bar')]
[1] 3
```

Is 1/0 is not evaluated as TRUE/FALSE in this case?

Comment: `a` is evaluated as index, like in a normal R vector. This is not related to data.table at all. You are just selecting `b` at locations `a`, where location zero does not exist in R. Hence, you are just selecting five time `b` at location 1. By your logic, even if `a` would be equal to 100, it would still work as 100 also converts to `TRUE` by `as.logical`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please considering putting just this comment in answer and I would like to accept this as answer. :)

Comment: I think the answer below is good enough, no? I don't really the rep. You can accept his answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where printing out intermediate results can help out a lot with what's going on.

```r
a = rep(c(1, 0), 5) 
b = c(rep('bar', 5), rep('baz', 5))
a
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
b
#>  [1] "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "baz" "baz" "baz" "baz" "baz"
b[a]
#> [1] "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar"
b[as.logical(a)]
#> [1] "bar" "bar" "bar" "baz" "baz"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

By using `b[a]` what you're telling `R` is that for each element of `a` you want the element of `b` that corresponds to the index that comes from `a`. And since `a` consists of only zeros and ones, you end up just getting the first index 5 times.